# Tensorflow slow performance on majority voting

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have implemented a majority voting algorithm (Counting prediction of different classifiers) on Tensorflow 1.10, and it's very slow (takes more than 3 hours for 10 classifiers) for predicting a dataset with size of 1000 (MNIST). Based on my guess it's because of calling session.run() a lot on my code, but how can i optimize it ?

```
def majority_voting(session, x, y):
    votes = []
    for i in range(number_of_ensemble_modules):
        # run the training
        feature_extractor = iterators[i][3]
        input, label = feature_extractor(x, y)
        transformed_x = session.run(input)
        ensemble_prediction = nn_models[0][i][0][3]
        prediction = session.run(ensemble_prediction, feed_dict={X: transformed_x, Y: y})
        votes.append(prediction[0])
    nearest_k_y, idx, vote = tf.unique_with_counts(tf.convert_to_tensor(votes, tf.int64))
    majority = tf.argmax(vote)
    predict_res = tf.gather(nearest_k_y, majority)
    return predict_res


def calculate_ensemble_accuracy():
    accuracy = 0
    for j in range(voting_iterations):
        accuracy += 0
        (features, labels) = session.run(next_element)
        vote = majority_voting(session, features, labels)
        correct_label = session.run(tf.argmax(labels, axis=1))
        if vote == correct_label[0]:
            accuracy += 1
    return accuracy
```

Comment: By "10 predictors" I take it that you actually mean 10 classifiers, right?

Comment: Yes, I mean a classifier (or a predictor)

Comment: These terms do not mean the same thing; a predictor is a *variable*, not a classifier.

Comment: My bad, i used a statical word in the programming context.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips that may fix your problem.

1- Do feature extraction before creating `tensorflow graph`. For example, if you create `TfIDF` feature vector, you can do it in preprocess step and save numpy for input of the graph.

```
input, label = feature_extractor(x, y)
```

2- Remove unnecessary `session.run()`. For example, when you call Optimizer it automatically call x_transformed.

```
transformed_x = session.run(input)
```

3- Use `tf.data` ([Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)) in a better way. It is unnecessary to call `sess.run(next_element)`. Because `next_element` is part of your graph.

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestions, the time consuming part is in the voting part which have to collect all the prediction (calling session.run() ), and i have to optimize that part.